# MATLAB progam for sorting numbers by numerical value

Tags: matlab

How can I write a function: `mpc(a)` which gets `a` as an array and sorts it's numbers by in decreasing order, but with negative numbers first, then zeros, and positive numbers at last?

For example  `a=[3,-1,-7,0,5,9,-5,0,12]` ----> `[-1,-5,-7,0,0,12,9,5,3]`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe not the most elegant, but:

```
b = -[sort(-a(a<0)) a(a==0) sort(-a(a>0))];
```

or

```
b = fliplr([sort(a(a>0)) a(a==0) sort(a(a<0))])
```